# Consulta Sql de fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que realizar una consulta Sql y solo **se debe** mostrar lo de hoy en adelante lo que está con una fecha anterior no se puede mostrar.

Tengo el problema que si lo pongo con formato DATETIME me coge los minutos y cuando haga la select lo que acabo de insertar no me lo va a mostrar después de 1 minuto....

Si lo pongo en formato String no puedo hacer el between entre fechas.........

```
Select descripcion from table_eventos where tiempo > sysdate()
```

**CREO** que la select sería así ...

En el insert me pone 2017/11/05 21:06:06 
*¿Cómo hacerlo para que solo coja el año/mes/día ?*

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos usas?

Comment: Estoy usando Mysql

y la select no devuelve nada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de `sysdate()`, puedes usar `curdate()` que solo devuelve la fecha corriente sin las horas y los minutos. La consulta sería:

```
Select descripcion
from table_eventos
where tiempo >= curdate()
```

Comment: Eres un máquina ! Gracias